# Price of an option that pays $1$ when the stock hits $\$H$ for the first time

Tags: finance

I am trying to understand the no arbitrage argument for to determine the price of an option that pays $1$ when the stock hits $\$H$ for the first time. The current price of the stock is $\$1$. The argument goes as follows.
I can buy $1/H$ of the stock now, which will give me $\$1$ when the stock becomes $\$H$. Thus the option can not be more than $1/H$. On the other hand, if the option price is $C$ less than $\$1/H$ then I can buy one option by borrowing $C$ shares of the stock. Once it hits $\$H$, exercise the option to make profit $1 - CH > 0$. So the price of the option can not be less than $1/H$.

What I don't understand about this argument is that how come one doesn't take into account the possibility that the stock never gets to $H$. In both cases, the argument assumes that the stock gets hits $H$ and deduces the conclusion. Any clarification would be appreciated. Thank you

Comment: How do you buy an option (at whichever price) by "borrowing $C$ shares of the stock" ?

Comment: I remember a result that the probability that stock never gets to $H$ over a period $(0,T)$ tends to $0$ when $T \to +\infty$. In other words, almost surely that the stock hits $H$.

Comment: @KurtG. apparently it means to borrow, then sell, and use that money to buy the option, exercise the option, buy back the stock and return

Comment: I can understand it better when we change the face value of the option payout to be $H$ when the stock hits $H$. The price for this option today is clearly the stock price today. Let's call this $S_0$. If the option price were less than $S_0$ you could buy the option for less than $S_0$ borrow a stock, sell it at at $S_0$ and pocket a profit. When the stock hits $H$ you get $H$ from the option which you use to buy back the stock and return it to the lender (zero sum game at the end). Profit was pocketed at the beginning. ...

Comment: ...The reason that this works without volatility is because we silently assumed that the option has a perpetual maturity. In reality such options expire after a while which changes the picture completely.

Comment: A more appropriate site for this would be https://quant.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For simplicity let's change the face value of the option payout to be $H$ when the stock hits the upper level $H\,.$ The price for this option today is clearly the stock price today. Let's call this $S_0\,.$

*Proof (I guess that's what you had in mind).* If the option price were less than $S_0$ you could buy the option for less than $S_0$ and borrow a stock, sell it at at $S_0$ and pocket a profit. When the stock hits $H$ you get $H$ from the option which you use to buy back the stock and return it to the lender (zero sum game at the end). Profit was pocketed at the beginning. $\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\Box$

Clearly, when the face value is one the option price will be $S_0/H\,.$

The reason that this works without volatility is because we silently assumed that the option has a perpetual maturity. In reality such options expire after a while which changes the picture completely:

Using the well-known Reiner & Rubinstein (1991b) formula for this option with maturity $T$ which we can find in [1] we get the following price-maturity relationship that depends on volatility $\sigma$ but -as expected- approaches the stock price of $S_0=100$ for large $T$:

[image]

The Reiner & Rubinstein (1991b) option pricing formula is
$$
H\Big(\frac{H}{S_0}\Big)^{\mu+\lambda}\Phi(-z)+H\Big(\frac{H}{S_0}\Big)^{\mu-\lambda}\Phi(-z+2\lambda\sigma\sqrt{T})
$$
where $\mu=\frac{r-q+\sigma^2/2}{\sigma}$ and $\lambda=\sqrt{\mu^2+\frac{2r}{\sigma^2}}$ and $z=\frac{\log(H/S_0)}{\sigma\sqrt{T}}+\lambda\sigma\sqrt{T}\,.$

Here $q$ is the continuous dividend yield of the stock. In our case it must be zero. If not, the lender will typically demand a fee which we have ignored in the above proof. A non zero dividend yield will change the option price even for very large maturities.

[1] E.G. Haug, *The Complete Guide to Option Pricing Formulas.*

Comment: I'm not convinced that this assuages OP's doubt. Even with an option with perpetual maturity, the stock price could never hit the upper level $H$.

Comment: You mean when $\sigma=0$ ? This case is totally trivial imho.

Comment: Why should $\sigma=0$?

Comment: In that case the stock never gets to $H$. In the case $\sigma>0$ it does.

Comment: Why? It seems to me you're implicitly assuming a Wiener process driving the stock price. The original argument proposed by OP tries to avoid that. Maybe it's unwarranted to make such a general argument, but that is exactly what I interpret OP's question to be about.

Comment: Yes. Wiener. It is OP's call now to confirm this. We can surely dream up lots of models where the stock never hits $H$. However I am wondering if they all can satisfy the requirement that the discounted stock price must be a martingale. Wiener will lurk behind those scenes.

Comment: Thank you for the comments and answer. In the question I was working on, I now came to the conclusion that it must be assuming, though not stated explicitly, that maturity is infinity and that at some point it will be $H$. Then the solution in the book makes sense.